# Python, pygame, how to draw an arc

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I'm trying to draw an arc in pygame, the actual size and position of the arc aren't important, at the moment all I get is an elipse.

My code:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 400, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()


    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (50, 50, 50, 50), 10, 20, 1)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Why does this draw a full circle instead of an arc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc):

> The two angle arguments are the initial and final angle in radians, with the zero on the right.

You are starting at 10 **radians**, and sweeping to 20. I assume you meant to do this in degrees. 10 radians is around 572 degrees.

Comment: Ah, so far to big, I've dropped it down to things like 1 - 2 and it works, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your radian values. Use Pi = 3.14 and then change it
for example :

pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255,255,255), [50,50,50,50], Pi/2, Pi, 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to calculate the angles in degrees and start drawing from the top:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 400, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

angle1 = 0
angle2 = 180

counter = 0
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (50, 50, 100, 100), ((angle1+90)/57), ((angle2+90)/57), 1)

    pygame.display.update()
```